# What would be a good way to encode high cardinality variables?

Tags: python

I have received a dataset with postcodes and car brands, and the 'one-hot' encoding would make the number of variables way too large.

I have seen examples where they transform the column with the high cardinality variable into the number of times each feature is in the column, but in the same article they said this technique was not advisable for post codes, is this true?